# NullpointerException in Spring autowiring even though bean definition is written in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I read about autowiring concept and trying to use it in my project. What I want is only one instance to be created for a particular class and that can be used with all the classes with autowiring.

I defined a bean in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="modifyService"
  class="com.xyz.service.ModifyPreferencesService"/>
```

No scope is defined, so it will be singleton.
Now I am using it in two classes.

```
class ABCEvaluationService{
@Autowired
ArrayList listIncident;
//This class is instantiating IncidentFactory with new keyword in a method
**//Methods using listIncident - getting empty list here**
}

class IncidentFactory{
**@Autowired
List listIncident
@Autowired
ModifyPreferencesService modifyService;**

//This class creates Incident Objects and add it to the listIncident.
**//Uses modifyService class objects - but I am getting null here**
}
```

**Issue is I am able to use it in first class but in the second class it gives me NullPointerException.** *This same thing is happening with other bean.* Am I doing this wrong. Is this not the purpose of autowiring. Please explain.. I am learning Spring and don't want to learn wrong concept.

Complete dispatcher-servlet.xml is(I cant really copy paste.. so there can by syntax error. Please ignore if any):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypack" />        
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/ABCReportForm"/>
        <bean class="com.xyz.interceptor.ValueStreamInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
  </mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

  <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

  <bean id="validator"
  class="com.xyz.validator.ABCValidator"/>
  <bean id="modifyService"
  class="com.xyz.service.ModifyPreferencesService"/>

  <bean id="abcService"
  class="com.xyz.service.ABCEvaluationService"/>
  <bean id="listIncident"
  class="java.utilArrayList"/>

  //Code for InternalResourceViewer
  </beans>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which packages are the two classes in? How have you configured     `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<context:component-scan base-package=...`

Comment: Yes I have configured xml file. It was working till I had only one class to use the bean/list. In the second usage only I am getting exception. Both classes are in different packages.

Comment: can you show your complete xml file

Comment: Yes.. I will do add in the question..

Comment: @King are `A` and `B` classes belongs to your working code? If so where they have configured as spring beans?

Comment: @TSurendra: I have added the exact class names now and the whole problem. Hopefully I have not put it in a confusing way. Let me know if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has quirky handling of collection objects. It presumes that you're asking for a number of beans that all implement some common interface. Autowiring a collection requires using its name.

Additionally:
- Use generics. 
- Use Spring Boot instead of manual configuration (with outdated versions). 
- Use constructor injection instead of field injection to make your code easier to test and maintain.

Comment: But this is also happening with modifyService bean.

Comment: @King Ah, then it looks like you have multiple problems. If you're learning, though, I recommend going with Boot so you just don't have to deal with all these details.

Comment: I am making this project to learn this. I cant really give up. I want to understand autowiring. And how it works and it can happen only if I am creating something. If it works for the bean, I will sort out for the list. Please help.

Comment: @King This is an *artificial* difficulty that doesn't exist anymore in modern systems. If you really want to understand it, then you may get some explanations now that it's day in the United States, but this multiple-context configuration issue is now obsolete, and I recommend not spending time on the details of an outdated configuration approach unless you're actually having to deal with an old system.

Comment: ohk.. So you suggest using Spring boot?